# How to properly escape characters for backquotes for ssh in Perl?

Tags: perl, bash, ssh

I have this code:

```
$script = "console.log(\"It works!\");";
$output = qx/ssh user@123.123.123.123 $script | interpreter/;
```

It's supposed to run `$script` through interpreter and write it into `$output`. The problem is that it doesn't work. How do I escape the characters correctly?

Comment: Are you wanting to run "interpreter" on the remote host or the local one?

Comment: i've already set up the nopassword connection via ssh between two VM's. I'm calling the interpreter, in this case node, that's on the remote host.

Comment: Your command doesn't quite make sense. Right now you're running `ssh ... | interpreter`, that is, you're piping the output of `ssh` into the local host's `interpreter`. If you want to run `interpreter` on the remote host, then you need to put it inside the argument to `ssh`; something like `qx/ssh user@123.123.123.123 '$script | interpreter'`.

Comment: You actually can’t do it safely for backticks under all circumstances. You have to use a pipe open with multiple separate arguments.

Answer (score 4):

Think about what you're trying to do just with ssh. Both of these produce the same output, but work differently:

```
ssh user@host 'echo "puts 2+2" | ruby'
echo "puts 2+2" | ssh user@host ruby
```

In the first, the remote shell is executing the pipeline. (If you don't have those single quotes, what happens?) In the second, it's piped through your local shell to the ssh command and the interpreter launched.

Rather than perform convoluted escapes of code to come out correctly when crammed through sh, I prefer to pipe the text in through stdin. It's just simpler.

Using [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/module/IPC%3a%3aRun) to do all the heavy lifting:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use IPC::Run qw(run);

my $in = <<FFFF;
2 + 2
8 * (2 + 3)
FFFF

my $cmd = [qw(ssh user@host perl calc.pl)];

run $cmd, \$in, \my $out, \my $err or die "ssh: $?";

print "out: $out";
print "err: $err";
```

(calc.pl is a simple infix calculator program that I had lying around)

Here's the output I get, running that:

```
out: 4
40
err: (SSH banners and pointless error messages)
```

---

Seeing `system` or `qx//` calls in a perl script is a sign of trouble. In general, I don't like having to think about shell syntax or shell quoting when I'm not writing shell; it has nothing to do with the problem I'm trying to solve, nor the tool I'm solving it with. (And that's ignoring any security implications.)

Oh, and if you don't have to muck with standard input but still want to execute and capture output from other programs, there's always [IPC::System::Simple](https://metacpan.org/module/IPC%3a%3aSystem%3a%3aSimple).

Comment: As an aside, I'd like to note that I was scarred by several of CPAN's SSH modules as a small child.

Comment: Me too, i've tried twenty times to install them properly but they don't like me.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using Perl, you should do it in Perl, and not a call out to an external command.

Have you tried the Perl module [Net::SSH::Perl](http://search.cpan.org/~turnstep/Net-SSH-Perl-1.34/lib/Net/SSH/Perl.pm)?

I would also use [qq](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) instead of quotation marks when setting the value of `$script`. Using `qq` removes the whole *how do I quote quotes* mess. What ever character comes after `qq` is your string delimiter. All of these are valid:

```
my $string = qq/This is a "string" with a quote/;
my $string = qq|This is a "string" with a quote|;
my $string = qq*This is a "string" with a quote*;
```

Special matching quote operators are `(` and `)`, `[` and `]`, and `{` and `}`:

```
my $string = qq(This (is (a "string" with) a) quote);
```

Note that I can use parentheses as my string delimiters even though my string has parentheses in it. This is okay as long as those parentheses are balanced. This one wouldn't work:

```
my $string qq(This is an "unbalanced" parentheses ) that breaks this statement);
```

But, then I can switch to square brackets or curly braces:

```
my $string qq[This is an "unbalanced" parentheses ) but still works.];
```

Here's a Perl version of your program:

```
use strict;     #Always use!
use warnings;   #Always use!
use Net::SSH::Perl;

#
# Use Constants to set things that are ...well... constant
#
use constant {
   HOST => "123.123.123.123",
   USER => "user",
};

my $script = qq[console.log("It works!");];
my $connection = Net::SSH::Perl->new(HOST);
$connection->login(USER);
my ($output, $stderr, $exit_code) = $connection->cmd($script);
```

Comment: Well that’s nice and all, people really should be taught how to run something in backquotes without worrying about escaping things.

Answer (score 0):

use [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aOpenSSH):

```
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new('user@123.123.123.123');
my $output = $ssh->capture({stdin_data => 'console.log("It works!");'},
                           'interpreter');
```